# Use of function templates

Tags: c++, templates

In my program,**T** may be of type **double** or of type **Eigen::MatrixXd**,so I use `is_same<T,double>::value` as condition to execute different code blocks。 But the program build faild.The failure description is Binary operator "=" no operator found that accepts a right-hand operand of type double。I know there is a problem with code`data_storage = *((double*)pt_property->data)` and code`data_storage(j, i) = *((double*)pt_property->data + pt_offset);` ,but i don't know why.
thanks.
Below is my code.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void MediumModelTest::ReadMatrixData(matvar_t* pt_mat_cp_data, T& data_storage, string property_name)
{
    matvar_t* pt_property = Mat_VarGetStructFieldByName(pt_mat_cp_data, property_name.c_str(), 0);
    ASSERT_NE(pt_property,nullptr);

    if (is_same<T,double>::value)
    {
        data_storage = *((double*)pt_property->data);
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int rows = pt_property->dims[0];
        unsigned int cols = pt_property->dims[1];
        unsigned int pt_offset = 0;

        data_storage.resize(rows, cols);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                data_storage(j, i) = *((double*)pt_property->data + pt_offset);
                pt_offset++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCu8E.png)

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that, along with the expected and actual output in text form (i.e. not as an image). As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you.It is the first time to use, I have no experience, I will learn more later.

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
if (is_same<T,double>::value)
```

to

```
if constexpr(is_same<T,double>::value)
```

In the plain "if" case the compiler still has to evaluate both branches, the compiler isn't allowed to discard the false branch even though the value is known at compile-time. But with the version you posted only one branch actually makes sense, depending on the type of T.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much。